# Normalization h/w

Tags: sql, database, normalization

[image]

Was told to put that into UNF/1NF/2NF/3NF, is this correct?

**Show the above data as a relation in UNF (unnormalised data).**

Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Phone, State, Postcode,Qty, ProductNo, Description, Unit price, Total, Subtotal, Shipping, Tax Rate, Date, OrderNo.))

**Show the data as a relation/s in 1NF.  (Indicate any keys.)**

Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, state, Phone, State, Postcode)
Product (ProductNo, Qty, Description, Unitprice, total, subtotal, shipping, Tax rate(s), CustomerID(FK).)
Order (OrderNo, Date, ProductNo(FK).)

**Show the data as a relation/s in 2NF.  (Indicate any keys.)**

Customer( CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Phone, State, Postcode)
Product ( ProductNo, Qty, Description, UnitPrice, CustomerID(FK), Total(FK).)
Order( OrderNo, Date, CustomerID(FK), ProductNo(FK).)
Total(Total, subtotal, shipping, Tax Rates, ProductNo(FK),CustomerID(FK)  )

**Show the data as a relation/s in 3NF.  (Indicate any keys.)**

Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Phone, State, Postcode)
Product (ProductNo, , Description, Unit Price. CustomerID(FK), Total(FK) )
Order (OrderNo, Date, CustomerID(FK).ProductNo(FK) )
Total(Total, subtotal, ProductNo(FK), CustomerID(FK) )
Shipping(Shipping, Tax Rates, Total(FK), OrderNo(FK) )
Qty( QtyID, Qty, ProductNo(FK), OrderNo(FK).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Show the above data as a relation in UNF (unnormalised data).
>
> Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Phone,
>   State, Postcode,Qty, ProductNo, Description, Unit price, Total,
>   Subtotal, Shipping, Tax Rate, Date, OrderNo.))

No, that's not right. There doesn't seem to be any customer ID number on the invoice. Normalization doesn't involve introducing new attributes. As an unnormalized collection of attributes, labeling that list as "Customer" is premature.

> Show the data as a relation/s in 1NF. (Indicate any keys.)
>
> - Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, state,
>     Phone, State, Postcode)
> - Product (ProductNo, Qty, Description,
>     Unitprice, total, subtotal, shipping, Tax rate(s), CustomerID(FK).)
> - Order (OrderNo, Date, ProductNo(FK).)

Drop CustomerID. (See above.) I'm guessing that one of the candidate keys for the "Product" table is "ProductNo".  If that's the case, why does that table include "CustomerID"?

> Show the data as a relation/s in 2NF. (Indicate any keys.)
>
> - Customer( CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Phone, State, Postcode)
> - Product ( ProductNo, Qty, Description, UnitPrice, CustomerID(FK), Total(FK).)
> - Order( OrderNo, Date, CustomerID(FK), ProductNo(FK).)
> - Total(Total, subtotal, shipping, Tax Rates, ProductNo(FK),CustomerID(FK) )

2NF has to do with removing partial key dependencies. What partial key dependency did you identify that justified creating the table "Total"? (Hint: there isn't any justification for that.) Do this thought experiment (or build it in SQL): If "Total" is the primary key for the table "Total", what will you do if two orders result in the same total?

I'll stop there for now, because you've *really* gotten off on the wrong foot. You need to *start* with a list of all attributes, then identify the candidate keys and functional dependencies. Without starting there, you're unlikely to find 3NF.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add our teacher told us to insert customerID into the information

Comment: I'm only just learning how to normalize databases (haven't actually started using SQL yet) so i've been having a bit of issues with these, not really sure what I need to do with total

Comment: Trust me; "Total" is *not* your problem. Candidate keys and functional dependencies are your problem.

Comment: imgur.com/N2hKMtQ  That is the version with the keys, the underline didn't copy over into the text here

Comment: Candidate keys and functional dependencies are still your problem.

Answer (score 4):

It looks good to me, but you are missing one **crucial piece** of the design. You haven't defined any Primary Keys on your tables, although you have identified the foreign keys (use the foreign keys you have to work out the primary keys on each of the tables :)).

Comment: Ah, that was my bad, I have them underlined in word, just didn't copy over here

Comment: @MatthewCorvi Then your design is fine :)

Comment: @MatthewCorvi Looks good, but you need to add Total and Shipping on there :)

Comment: Total would go to Product/Customer and Shipping to Total/Order right?

Comment: @MatthewCorvi Yeah, according to your tables defined above :)

Comment: One last question, would this be a correct ERD for the two added? Usually have issues with ERDs the most   http://imgur.com/1OhyJAx

Answer (score 0):

An interesting thing about invoices....J Frompton orders a rake today, but some time in the future the price will change.  However, that does not change the price Frompton payed today.

Once invoices are fulfilled, they really should be moved to a table that is 1NF.

Comment: Question is purely theory, and is just that part